# Erro UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Pessoal meu app está pronto e quando eu compilo ele, ele ficando dando esse erro:

> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Como faço pra parar de receber esse erro? Não compila, ele para nisso.

Alguém sabe porque ele para no debug?

Comment: Não seria ```Debug.Log``` em vez de ```Debug:Log```

Comment: esse ai é o error a funcao eu coloquei assim Debug.Log (this + "  ");

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, o método `Debug.Log` não está reconhecendo o objeto `this` que você passou como parâmetro.

[**`Debug.Log`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html)

```
public static void Log(object message);
public static void Log(object message, Object context);
```

- `message` -> String ou objeto a ser convertido em representação de string para exibição;
- `Object` -> Objeto ao qual a mensagem se aplica;

Você passou um objeto que não pode ser convertido em string - o `this`.

Construa uma mensagem de erro reconhecível e passe-a no parâmetro.